# Adding a div element to another part of the website when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code a jQuery script that adds some functionality to a button. 
Basically when I click a button (ex: Settings), I want to add that specific text (ex: Settings), to a different div (the div is predefined with css rules), just like how a google chrome tab works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wButtons = document.getElementById('#wrapper');
    $(".buttonSettings").click(function() {
        var domElement = $('<span>Settings</span>').appendTo(wButtons);
        $(this).after(domElement);
    });
});
```

The code works partially, but it won't append to `#wrapper`, just under the `.buttonSettings` div. Also I should mention that I have a predefined number of tabs (max 6).

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to inserting `span` into `#wrapper`?

Comment: No. I want to add the text 'Settings'  (which is a predefined button), to a different div that acts like a button. And in my case I have 6 predefined tabs. If I click Settings 6 times, I need 6 tabs with content 'Settings' for easy access. I have 7 buttons that are located on the left of the webpage, right? If I click any of them, they will activate a button in the wrapper area ( max 6 buttons or tabs as I call them ).

Comment: Now, what is problem in my answer or what in it need to change?

Comment: Sir, it works! Thank you so much. I will adjust the code to limit it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append html string into element, use jquery `appendTo()` method like this.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
     $("<span>Span content</span>").appendTo("#wrapper");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Append</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="wrapper">Wrapper content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove # from getElementById and in this case this == button,

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var wButtons = document.getElementById('wrapper');
$(".buttonSettings").click(function() {
        wButtons.innerHTML += '<span>BALALALALA</span>'; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately it does not work in my case. I've tried to adapt the selectors correctly, but it won't add the span.